# Create a folder using DTE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, envdte

How do you create a physical folder using DTE and have it added to the current path within a visual studio project? Ideally I'd like to be able to do this using PowerShell (through StudioShell). I would like to automate creating a directory structure that I use frequently.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use foo.[ProjectItems.AddFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projectitems.addfolder.aspx), where foo is your EnvDTE.Project or any other folder (EnvDTE.ProjectItem).